# Multiple choice variable to specify folder rights in Ansible Tower

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-template, ansible-tower

I have a playbook that creates a directory in Ansible Tower.
I have a survey with a multiple choice options to choose the permission for this folder.

The playbook is:

```yaml
- name: Create a directory
  hosts: localhost
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Create directory
      file:
        path: /test
        state: directory
        mode: u={{ user_perm }},g={{ group_perm }},o={{ other_perm }}
        owner: 'root'
        group: 'root'
```

When I execute the template in Ansible Tower I have to specify in the survey, via a multiple choice, the parameters: `r`, `w`, `x`. My intention is that I could combine this variables: `rw`, `r`, `rx`.

After specifying the parameters in multiple choice the summary that Tower shows:

```yaml
user_perm:
  - r
group_perm:
  - r
  - w
other_perm:
  - x
```

And the error message:

> bad symbolic permission for mode: u=['r'], "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0750", "msg": "mode must be in octal or symbolic form""

Should I change the way the playbook handle variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a valid set of permission matching your example would be

```yaml
mode: u=r,g=rw,o=x
```

You can simply join your lists:

```yaml
mode: >-
  u={{ user_perm | join -}}
  ,g={{ group_perm | join -}}
  ,o={{ other_perm | join }}
```